# Materialized view staleness is compilation_error after successful refresh

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, materialized-views

I have 1 materialized view and compiled it without any error and even a manually refresh does not have compilation error. The materialized view is also searchable and contains values. But once you checked the staleness of the view, it is compilation_error. Also the object has red X in SQL Dev. Below is how I did my scenario.

- Execute the Materialized view in SQL*Plus at APR-30 which will autorefresh every 9pm (see actual MV code below).
- Execute the MVIEW LOGS in SQL*Plus.
  In SQL Dev, Checked the Materialized view Details Tab. STALENESS is FRESH which is good.
- After 2 days (MAY-02), Checked Materialized view Details Tab. STALENESS is NEEDS_COMPILE, which is valid  and should be changed on next refresh.
- Checked if there are new records to add in Source Tables (i.e. Select * from MLOG$_FACILITIES).
- Since the autorefresh does not process since APR-30. On May-04, manually
- Executed the refresh ‘F’ but a Compilation error suggested to run Complete refresh instead.
- Execute Complete refresh, it is Successful.
- Check all_mview table. The last refresh date was updated to May-04.
- Check the Details of Materialized view, it has a STALENESS value of COMPILATION_ERROR
- I tried to execute refresh ‘FAST’ again but thestaleness value does not change.

> Note: Until now the refresh date is still May-04 and Staleness = COMPILATION_ERROR.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_XXX
SELECT FAC.ID FACILITY_ID,
         FAC.EXTERNAL_FACILITY_ID,
         FACTYPE.FACILITY_TYPE_CODE,
         FACTYPE.FACILITY_TYPE_NAME,
         FAC.ASSET_TAG,
         FAC.ORG_UNIT_TILE_ID TILE,
         FAC.CRITICALITY,
         FAC.FACILITY_STATUS,
         ATLAS.ATLAS,
         ATLAS.DESCRIPTION ATLAS_DESC,
         ORGUNIT.SHORT_TEXT ORG_UNIT,
         SUBSTR(ORGUNIT.SHORT_TEXT, 2, 1) DIVISION_CODE,
         TRIM(FAC.DIRECT_ADDRESS_INFORMATION) DIRECT_ADDRESS_INFORMATION,
         TRIM(FMA_A.ADDRESS_1) ADDR_STREET_NO,
         TRIM(FMA_A.ADDRESS_3) ADDR_STREET_PREDIRECTION,
         TRIM(FMA_A.ADDRESS_4) ADDR_STREET_NAME,
         TRIM(FMA_A.ADDRESS_5) ADDR_STREET_TYPE,
         TRIM(FMA_A.ADDRESS_6) ADDR_STREET_POSTDIRECTION,
         TRIM(FMA_A.ADDRESS_9) ADDR_STREET_CITY,
         FAC.RJRN_JURISDICTION JURISDICTION,
         TRIM(FMA_A.ADDRESS_11) ADDR_STREET_ZIPCODE,
         TAX_D.TAXING_DISTRICT_CODE,
         TRIM(FAC_CH_CRS1.VALUE) CROSSSTREET1_NAME,
         TRIM(FAC_CH_CRSTP1.VALUE) CROSSSTREET1_TYPE,
         TRIM(FAC_CH_CRS2.VALUE) CROSSSTREET2_NAME,
         TRIM(FAC_CH_CRSTP2.VALUE) CROSSSTREET2_TYPE,
         FAC.GPS_LATITUDE,
         FAC.GPS_LONGITUDE,
         FAC.X_COORDINATE,
         FAC.Y_COORDINATE,
         FAC_CH_ASSTID.VALUE ASST_ID,
         FAC_CH_UFID.VALUE UFID_NMBR,
         FAC.ROWID ROWID1,
         FACTYPE.ROWID ROWID2,
         FACORGUNIT.ROWID ROWID3,
         ORGUNIT.ROWID ROWID4,
         ATLAS.ROWID ROWDID5,
         FMA_A.ROWID ROWID6,
         FAC_CH_CRS1.ROWID ROWID7,
         FAC_CH_CRS2.ROWID ROWID8,
         FAC_CH_CRSTP1.ROWID ROWID9,
         FAC_CH_CRSTP2.ROWID ROWID10,
         FAC_TD_MUNI.ROWID ROWID11,
         TAX_D.ROWID ROWID12,
         FAC_CH_ASSTID.ROWID ROWID13,
         FAC_CH_UFID.ROWID ROWID14
  FROM   FACILITIES FAC,
         FACILITY_TYPE FACTYPE,
         FACILITY_ORG_UNITS FACORGUNIT,
         ORG_UNITS ORGUNIT,
         ORG_UNIT_ATLASES ATLAS,
         FM_ADDRESS FMA_A,
         FACILITY_CHARS FAC_CH_CRS1,
         FACILITY_CHARS FAC_CH_CRSTP1,
         FACILITY_CHARS FAC_CH_CRS2,
         FACILITY_CHARS FAC_CH_CRSTP2,
         FACILITY_TAX_DISTRICTS FAC_TD_MUNI,
         TAXING_DISTRICT TAX_D,
         FACILITY_CHARS FAC_CH_ASSTID,
         FACILITY_CHARS FAC_CH_UFID
  WHERE  (FAC.FLTY_FACILITY_TYPE = FACTYPE.FACILITY_TYPE_CODE (+))
         AND (FAC.ID = FACORGUNIT.FACL_ID (+))
         AND (FAC.ORG_UNIT_ATLAS_ID = ATLAS.SHORT_TEXT (+))
         AND (
              FAC.ID = FMA_A.ENTITY_KEY_VALUE_1 
              AND FMA_A.ENTITY_KEY_NAME_1 = 'ID'
              AND FMA_A.ENTITY_NAME = 'FACILITIES'
              AND FMA_A.ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = 'A'
              )
         AND (FAC.ID = FAC_CH_CRS1.FACL_ID AND FAC_CH_CRS1.FCHT_RFCT_CHAR_TYPE = 'CROSSSTREET1')
         AND (FAC.ID = FAC_CH_CRSTP1.FACL_ID AND FAC_CH_CRSTP1.FCHT_RFCT_CHAR_TYPE = 'CROSSTYPE1')
         AND (FAC.ID = FAC_CH_CRS2.FACL_ID AND FAC_CH_CRS2.FCHT_RFCT_CHAR_TYPE = 'CROSSSTREET2')
         AND (FAC.ID = FAC_CH_CRSTP2.FACL_ID AND FAC_CH_CRSTP2.FCHT_RFCT_CHAR_TYPE(+) = 'CROSSTYPE2')
         AND (FAC.ID = FAC_TD_MUNI.FACL_ID (+))
         AND (FAC_TD_MUNI.TXDS_TAX_DISTRICT = TAX_D.TAXING_DISTRICT_CODE (+))
         AND (FAC.ID = FAC_CH_ASSTID.FACL_ID AND FAC_CH_ASSTID.FCHT_RFCT_CHAR_TYPE(+) = 'ASSETID')
         AND (FAC.ID = FAC_CH_UFID.FACL_ID AND FAC_CH_UFID.FCHT_RFCT_CHAR_TYPE(+) = 'UFID')
         AND FACORGUNIT.ORGU_ID = ORGUNIT.ID 
         AND FAC.FACILITY_STATUS = 'Installed'
         AND FAC.ASSET_MANAGER_FACILITY_YN = 'Y';


CREATE INDEX MV_XXX_FAC_ID ON schema.MV_XXX(FACILITY_ID);
CREATE INDEX MV_XXX_EXT_FAC_ID ON schema.MV_XXX(EXTERNAL_FACILITY_ID);
CREATE INDEX MV_XXX_FLTY_TYPE ON MV_XXX(FACILITY_TYPE_CODE, FACILITY_TYPE_NAME);
CREATE INDEX MV_XXX_ASSET_TAG ON MV_XXX(ASSET_TAG);
CREATE INDEX MV_XXX_TILE ON MV_XXX(TILE);
CREATE INDEX MV_XXX_ATLAS ON MV_XXX(ATLAS);
CREATE INDEX MV_XXX_ADDR_ST ON MV_XXX(ADDR_STREET_NAME);
CREATE INDEX MV_XXX_MUNI ON AEC_XXX(MUNICIPALITY);
CREATE INDEX MV_XXX_ASST_ID ON MV_XXX(ASST_ID);
CREATE INDEX MV_XXX_UFID ON MV_XXX(UFID_NMBR);
```

Comment: I add `sql` tag for making more sense, but please add tag of your DBMS ;).

Comment: What is the exact version of your DB?

Comment: SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Comment: Anyone that could help me please...

Comment: Can someone help me with this issue please?